# How to check if a string is of a specific pattern

Tags: java, regex

The user inputs any string and the program distinguishes whether the string is qualifying product ID or not.

The qualifying product IDs are any of string consists of two capitals and four numbers. (For example, "TV1523")

How can I make this program?

Comment: -1: sounds like homework, you should probably try solving it for yourself

Comment: Maybe give him or her a little hint and then downvote for not marking homework ;). I would say use a regex?

Comment: You should read up on regular expressions. You could try the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should compare the string using a regular expression, for example:

`str.matches("^[A-Z]{2}\\d{4}")` will give you a boolean value as to whether it matches or not.

The regular expression works as follows:

```
^ Indicates that the following pattern needs to appear at the beginning of the string.
[A-Z] Indicates that the uppercase letters A-Z are required.
{2} Indicates that the preceding pattern is repeated twice (two A-Z characters).
\\d Indicates you expect a digit (0-9)
{4} Indicates the the preceding pattern is expected four times (4 digits).
```

Using this method, you can loop through any number of strings and check if they match the criteria given.

You should read up on regular expressions though, there are more efficient ways of storing the pattern if you are worried about performance.

Comment: You don't missed the `$`, your `^` is unnecessary. The `matcher()` method tries to match the complete input against the pattern, so it has the two anchors "build in". [class Matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). Anyway +1 for the explanation of the pattern.

Answer (score 6):

You should have a closer look at regular expressions. A tutorial is e.g. here at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

An example for your Pattern could be

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d{4}$
```

you can see it [here on Regexr.com](http://regexr.com?2v1no) a good place to test regular expressions online.

Here is [java regex tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) there you can see how you call them in Java.

Comment: Aaaa. I missed the $.  Well done!

Comment: I really appreciate your good answer. Your answer is almost perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String id = "TV1523";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
    String tocompare = br.readLine();
    if(tocompare.equals(id)) { //do stuff
```

something like that, except you might wand to enclose the readLine() within a try catch instead :x

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems like only 'TV1523' is valid in your answer. I mean all of two capitals and four numbers are valid.

Comment: @schizoid322 that's a sample, try to code a bit by yourself ;)