# Java: Forcing characters in a String to be numbers or letters

Tags: java, string

`vatNumber` should be seen as an 8 character string where the first two 
characters are digits and the remaining six characters are numeric e.g. `GB123456`.

I need to write a `getVatNumber` method so how would I go about writing the method in a way where it would display an error if the first two characters aren't letters and the last 6 aren't numeric

Comment: If *you* need to write this method, please show us the result of your effort.

Comment: i think `GB` are not digits. I think you mean `[A-Z]{2}\\d{4}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string is of a specific pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914069/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-of-a-specific-pattern) See answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7914390/1980909

Comment: @Lutz Horn The reason i'm asking is because I really wouldn't know how to go about doing it, I know there is a way I just don't know what it is haha

Comment: Others have pointed out how to check for the correct format (or where to find that information). However I advise you not to put this code into the `getVatNumber()` method but rather into the method that determines (reads, calculates, asks for) the vat number.

Comment: Look into using regular expressions (like @AvinashRaj suggested) or you can do a substring of the first 2 characters and the last 6 and do validation that way (checking that the string is at least 8 characters long first, of course)

Answer (score 1):

I know a regular expression would be 'easier', but since I'm assuming this is an assignment, let's see if we can break things down into easier portions.

In your example case, let's assume `String vatNumber = "GB123456";`

We need to ensure the first 2 **characters** are letters and the last 6 are **numbers**. Firstly, **given a String, how do you look at a single character**, say the first G?

By now, you should have learned about something like `vatNumber.charAt(0)` which will give you the character at a particular *index*. From here, save this as a `char` variable (something like `char letter1`).

Now, I'm making the assumption you've just learned about the `Character` class and some of its wonderful methods, which allows you to do something like `Character.isLetter(letter1)` which will produce a **true** if the first letter is in fact `G`.

Do this same process for all 8 characters (or use a loop instead) and `if` they are all true, then you don't display an error, `else` you do.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning how to ensure that the string is exactly 8 characters long.

Comment: @Adam G Thanks for the help! Howveer when I tried saying that       vatNumber.charAt(0) = charletter1;    It gave me an error "unexpected Type, Required variable Found Value

Comment: @Patterrz one of the issues is that Java runs off what I call "left-to-right" association, which means the right side of the **assignment operator** (the '=' symbol) is the **what** and the left side is the **where** (that is, where in memory).

You need to place the char letter1 on the left, and the vatNumber.charAt(0) on the right.

Comment: @Adam G. ah right thanks! I've gotten everything in the right order but now i'm having this problem http://prntscr.com/66pk69 the error is at the bottom of the screenshot

Comment: @Patterrz take a look at this [link to TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/character_isletter.htm). Every data type (`int`, `double`, `char`) have something known as a **Wrapper Class**. This **Wrapper Class** holds some nice premade methods that someone smarter than both of us combined made (for example, `isLetter()` and `isDigit()`). So how do we use them? Again, the `Character` class is the **wrapper** to the `char` data type (`Integer` to `int` and `Double` to `double`). Well by *invoking* `Character.isLetter(...)` with our newly extracted letter, then we get a true/false.

Answer (score 0):

```
String var = "AD456565";
    if (var.length() == 8) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{6}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(var);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("mached");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Match not found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: first we do basic validation like total length , then we  match the string pattern like first two char are alphabets in both lower and upper case  followed by 6 digit

Answer (score 0):

Set up a regular expression for the desired VAT pattern

```
    static Pattern vatPattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z]{2}\\d{6}$");
```

and then try matching each pattern against it.

```
        if(vatPattern.matcher(pattern).matches()) {
            System.out.println(pattern + " matches");
        } else {
            System.out.println(pattern + " fails");
        }
```

Note that the VAT pattern should specify a beginning and end of string to prevent a match of "ABC123456".